# Wireless is connecting but Internet is not working

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

In my laptop, its connecting to the wireless device and everything is fine. But, its not connecting to Internet. How can I fix this properly?

Comment: make sure you have configured your router...

Comment: How to configure the router

Comment: do you know what brand and model router you have? and are you plugging it into an internet-receiving connection (from the ISP)

Comment: you have to enter the ip of ur router to cofigure it...it mostly 192.168.1.1 and the uname and passwd both are genereally admin...after that,tou need to search on net how to configure your specific router(specific model no)

Comment: Could you run the command ifconfig in a terminal and post the output here.  That may help see what is wrong.

Comment: Without the information @Jazz has requested above (the output of `ifconfig`), or some other equivalent information, it's not likely this can be answered. I'd suggest closing this question as *too localized*. @KAISERVIGNESH You can provide additional information by editing your question. If we *have* closed the question when you do this, I recommend also posting a comment here, requesting that it be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to load a page in your web browser does it say something like "Server Not Found"? If so, try this command in the terminal:

```
sudo dhclient
```

It will ask for your password. Enter that then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Then reopen your web browser and try again. If that doesn't work sorry, that's all I know of.

Comment: Awesome, that worked  for me. I was messing with lm-profiler and I may have done something that screwed my network stuff.